# Indicate an important date on a chart with either a guideline (with text) or an opened callout

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking for a way to indicate key dates on a highchart with a label eg Public Holiday. I can't find a way to add labeled guidelines or add an opened callout to a point? Help appreciated.

Comment: Could you illustrate the way you want it to look? There's about a million different ways to highlight a point/x-value/y-value using lines, labels...

Comment: Thanks for responding. Something like this http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html 
or http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/ (scroll to annotation example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highstock you have series type called `flags` which is a opened callout (similar to [Dygraphs annotation](http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html)). This is probably the closest fit to the indicators you referred. See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2BGSK/) of how it looks. Note how this example uses the Highstock source file, but builds a Highcharts chart. See [this documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/flag-series) for official information.

In Highcharts you can highlight points, labels and value in a wide variety of ways. First of you can add data labels to your points, which renders text next to it. Secondly you can use [plot lines](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines) to highlight certain values along an axis. See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m5exv28o/) of how both of these options can be used.

Of course there are lots of ways to improve and build upon this out of the box functionality, but that is up to your specific demands and desires.

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for - thanks so much.